# Aplicação Angular 4 fica mais lento com o passar do tempo

Tags: angular, google-chrome, raspberry-pi

Olá. 
Tenho uma aplicação Angular 4.3.5 que fica mais lenta quando é usado depois de um tempo (~20 minutos).

**Meu cenário é mais ou menos isso:**

- API Rest e os arquivos estáticos do Angular ficam em um RaspberryPI B 3
- Aproximadamente 30 RaspberryPI B 3 acessam a aplicação Angular através do Chromium (versões 58 e 60)

**O que ocorre:**

- As requisições HTTP do Angular ficam mais lentas conforme o tempo passa. Exemplo: de ~100 ms para 2 segundos

**Informações adicionais:**

- Se eu presiono F5 no Chromium a aplicação Angular volta ao normal
- Angular utiliza este template https://themeforest.net/item/primer-angular-2-material-design-admin-template/19228165
- Angular utiliza um aplicativo para Google Chrome/Chromium, que eu escrevi, para se comunicar com um arduino através da porta serial (APIs do Chrome que utilizo: chrome.runtime.sendMessage, chrome.runtime.connect and chrome.serial)
- Os clientes, RaspberryPI, tem recursos disponíveis (CPU e memória) quando a aplicação fica lenta
- A aplicação Angular armazena quase nada no navegador

Comment: O que sua aplicação faz?

Comment: Reformulei melhor a pergunta @Giovane muito obrigado!

Comment: Provavelmente é memory leak, verifique se você está dando unsubscribe nos seus services.